# CreateTextNode from multiple value in Read-host

Tags: xml, api, powershell, url, xmldocument

For Powershell - Is there a way to easily grab the values from Read-host and have them separate in new lines with the created XML tags?  For example, here's the script I'm working on:

```
$Response = 'Y'
$URLName = $Null
$SecondURLName = @()

# Enter URL

do {
    [array]$URLName = Read-Host "Please enter the URL (Example:  www.example.com)" 
    $Response = Read-Host 'Do you want to add more URLs? (y/n)'
    $SecondURLName += $URLName
}
Until ($Response -eq 'n')

# Create a new XML File with member root node
$XMLDocument=New-Object System.XML.XMLDocument

# New Node
$MemberRoot=$XMLDocument.CreateElement("url")

# Append as child to an existing node
$XMLDocument.appendChild($MemberRoot)

# Add URL to member Node
$XMLEntry=$MemberRoot.appendChild($XMLDocument.CreateTextNode("$SecondURLName"))

# Save File 
$XMLDocument.Save("urls.xml")
```

Under both Read-Host input, if I were to put 2 values such as "website.com" and "website2.com", it will result in the xml document as follow:

```
<url>website.com website2.com</url>
```

What I'm trying to aim for is the following results in the xml document:

```
<url>website.com</url>
<url>website2.com</url>
```

There has to be an easier way to separate the values from the read-host and format them separately in the xml document.  Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

i think you'll have to wrap the second half of your script in a foreach loop because of your $SecondURLName variable

```
$SecondURLName = @('website.com', 'website2.com')

$SecondURLName

"$SecondURLName"

foreach ($line in $SecondURLName ) { $line }

foreach ($line in $SecondURLName ) { "$line" }
```

Comment: I had my suspicions to use foreach loop, but it hasn't been properly working on my end.  Still ending up with the same results as so:  <url>website.com website2.com </url>